# Any way to make Google Chrome Inspector open in new window in Chrome 16?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, ux

I'm using Chrome `16.0.912.59 beta-m` at work; my home machine runs Chrome `15.0.874.121 m`. Running multiple monitors means having the Inspector open on the second window makes for far quicker iterative development when I'm bugfixing my crappy CSS. However in Chrome 16, it opens in a draggable pane at the bottom of the browser window -- and there seems to be no way to detach the window to allow me to run my mouse through the HTML tree and see the visual identifier in the browser window.

Is there a command switch to make the Inspector behave as v15, or is this behaviour fixed now? Am I missing something blindingly obvious? There's no option to revert the display appearance in the Inspector options.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to answer my own question, partially because I'm an idiot. There's an Undock button in the very bottom-left corner of the Inspector window; I couldn't see this... because I have a small cut-out picture of a kitty cat wedged into the bottom-left corner of my laptop monitor.

I deserve no points for this. ;-)

Comment: No worries! It is worth noting that when you undock the Developer Tools, it remains undocked even after closing the window. :)

Comment: Mmm! Indeed, that's why I couldn't figure out how to undock on the work machine... Because obviously I'd clicked undock months ago at home then promptly forgotten ever having done so.

@studiohack who closed as 'too localized' -- the Inspector is a fairly mature feature in Chrome now; it wasn't their changing of its UI that provoked this question being asked, it was my own ineptitude. :-)

Comment: In this case, I am assuming 'too localized' is referring to the fact that very few people will have a picture of a cat covering up the bottom-left of their screen. :P

Comment: ........................... there is that. xD (makes for a far more pleasant Start button, mind)

Comment: Thanks goodness I came across this.  It was driving me crazy trying to figure it out.